# How can you provide this access specifier protection in python?

Tags: python, oop, private, access-specifier

Here is the scenario I am currently dealing with.
There is a class called Service. Basically, only a single object of this can be created by a node. Once this object is created it is passed from one node to another node.

```
Class Service:
 int valueOfA=0;
 int valueOfB=0;
 int valueOfC=0;
 int valueOfD=0;
```

Now , Lets say A instantiates an object obj of this class. now A should be able to increment only

```
 obj.valueOfA++
```

Similarly B should be able to increment only

```
 obj.valueOfB++
```

But any node can read the value of A or B or C. Here each node is identified by its IP address. Meaning node A has a separate IP addr, node B has a separate IP address so on and so forth.

How can I implement something like this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has no automatic access specifier protection like `public` or `private`.  But you can always implement the logic yourself using a method.  Do something like:

```
def incrementA(self, node):
  if node.name == "Node A": self.valueOfA += 1
  else: raise ValueError("node is not authorized to increment A")
```

Also, Python has no `++` operator. You need to use `+=` to increment.

Comment: thank you for that. This is my first time programming in python and I was just trying to see if python has any such magic